# Eclipse SQL Server Connection

Tags: sql-server, eclipse, database-connection

I am trying to establish connection to SQL Server from eclipse.
I added to the project build path the jar  sqlserverjdbc.jar .
This is my code:

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

    //Connection m_Connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
    //        "jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=TMO", "****", "****");
    String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://10.25.50.14;databaseName=TMO;integratedSecurity=true";
    //Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        Statement m_Statement = conn.createStatement();
```

When I call getConnection(url) I get an error:

Nov 17, 2014 1:08:43 AM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection 
SEVERE: Java Runtime Environment (JRE) version 1.7 is not supported by this driver. Use the sqljdbc4.jar class library, which provides support for JDBC 4.0.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Java Runtime Environment (JRE) version 1.7 is not supported by this driver. Use the sqljdbc4.jar class library, which provides support for JDBC 4.0.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.(SQLServerConnection.java:238)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:841)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.ccih.analytics.clustering.tmo.DexRunner.getKeyPhrasesFromNewNlpDB_W_SAMPLE(DexRunner.java:394)
    at com.ccih.analytics.clustering.tmo.DexRunner.main(DexRunner.java:59)
ERROR: JDWP Unable to get JNI 1.2 environment, jvm->GetEnv() return code = -2
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_NO_JNI_ENV(183):  [../../../src/share/back/util.c:838]

Am I using the wrong jar ? I checked my eclipse project in the 'Referenced Libraries' and I saw the entry of the related jar with all the .class files

Comment: it is written in the error message itself please use sqljdbc4.jar

Answer (score 1):

Yep You are Using the wrong jar which is not compatible for your JRE. I had same problem and i tried using the sqljdbc4.jar library and it worked completely fine for me.You can download .jar from here.[DOWNLOAD](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=11774)

i hope this helps.